# Rename endpoint /openapi and /openapi/ui

Tags: swagger, openapi, microprofile

The API documentation created using OpenAPI is usually called using the endpoints */openapi* (YAML) or */openapi/ui* (Frontend).
How can I rename these endpoints for that I can call e.g. */myappapi* and */myappapi/ui* respectively? (OpenAPI 3)

Comment: What server-side framework do you use - Springfox, Swashbuckle, Swagger-Net, Swagger-PHP, something else?

Comment: I work with _Eclipse MicroProfile_.

Answer (score 1):

This massively depends on how you're generating that OpenAPI. From your comment I see that you're using Eclipse MicroProfile and I've not come across that before, but a quick DuckDuckGo shows this extension might be what you're up to: https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-open-api

I couldn't see any specific config options to change the endpoint, but you could always slap a nginx redirect in there.

If you're finding limitations with the way you're generating OpenAPI to be a problem, I recommend not doing that.

Of all the approaches: Annotations, DSL, writing YAML by hand in text-editors, or GUI's, I can't help but recommend the GUI approach as it allows for API Design First for new APIs and new functionality in old APIs.

I just did a huge talk about that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfkppuQ-Eg0&feature=youtu.be

Blog version: https://stoplight.io/blog/api-design-first-vs-code-first/

Otherwise, see if you can pick that extension apart and tweak the config options until it does whatever you want. :)